# List indicies must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

When I try to expose nested attributes in a json using json_normalise, I can't bring back the attributes of one of the nested objects. I'm trying to return the 'type' as a column but the following error is returned: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The Json structure looks like this:

```
[{
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.AccidentDetail, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": 269639,
    "lat": 51.5169,
    "lon": -0.1428,
    "location": "Regent Street junction with Little Portland Street",
    "date": "2016-06-04T20:00:00Z",
    "severity": "Slight",
    "borough": "City of Westminster",
    "casualties": [{
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Casualty, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "age": 23,
        "class": "Driver",
        "severity": "Slight",
        "mode": "PedalCycle",
        "ageBand": "Adult"
    }],
    "vehicles": [{
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Vehicle, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "type": "PedalCycle"
    }, {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Vehicle, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "type": "Car"
    }]
```

the code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


# load data using Python JSON module
with open('/Users/samappleton/Documents/Python/Project/api_response_2023-01-31-13:22.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
 
# Normalizing data
try:

    df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['casualties'],
    meta =[
        'id',
        'lat',
        'lon',
        'location',
        'date',
        'severity',
        'borough',
        ['vehicles']['type']

    ],record_prefix ='casualties.')

    #
     print(df)
    # df.to_csv("Documents/Python/Project/CSV_Output.csv") 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

Any ideas on how I can extract the vehicles.type column?

Thank you

Comment: I tried to add 'vehicles' to the record_path but i'm not sure it can take multiple arguments

Comment: I'd guess you probably want something like `['vehicles'][:]['type']`, because otherwise, `['vehicles']` is a list that you are indexing with the string `'type'`

Comment: I think that the last **]** and **}** are missing

Comment: `['vehicles']['type']` is an an attempt to index the list `['vehicles']` with the "index" `['type']` It's not a "compound" key for the JSON you are normalizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not clear what is your precise goal. However, I try to show you a solution.
If you want to *flatten* both **casualties** and **vehicle** maybe you should normalize the json once with *casualties* as record path, and another time with *vehicles*

### Define Data

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

string = '''{
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.AccidentDetail, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "id": 269639,
        "lat": 51.5169,
        "lon": -0.1428,
        "location": "Regent Street junction with Little Portland Street",
        "date": "2016-06-04T20:00:00Z",
        "severity": "Slight",
        "borough": "City of Westminster",
        "casualties": [{
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Casualty, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "age": 23,
            "class": "Driver",
            "severity": "Slight",
            "mode": "PedalCycle",
            "ageBand": "Adult"
        }],
        "vehicles": [{
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Vehicle, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "type": "PedalCycle"
        }, {
            "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AccidentStats.Vehicle, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
            "type": "Car"
        }]}'''


data = json.loads(string)
```

### Normalize Json

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['vehicles'],
   meta=['id', 'lat','lon', 'location', 'date', 'severity', 
   'borough', 'casualties'], record_prefix='vehicle.') # I do not include $type key

df2 = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ['casualties'], record_prefix = 'casualties.', 
   meta='id')

# merge two different nested listed of dictionaries flattened in dataframes
res = df.merge(df2)

print(res.columns) 
print(res) # shape (2,15)
```

### Result

```bash
Index(['vehicle.$type', 'vehicle.type', 'id', 'lat', 'lon', 'location', 
       'date','severity', 'borough', 'casualties.$type', 'casualties.age',
       'casualties.class', 'casualties.severity', 'casualties.mode',
       'casualties.ageBand'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you Stefano, this is exactly what I was after :)